# Insert postgres JSON[] data type data into MSSQL data table

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I'm trying insert Postgres datatable data to MSSQL data table. Postgres data table contain JSON[] type data. What is the compatible data type in MSSQL?

Thanks.

Comment: select json_column::text from table will give you varchar with json

Comment: i meant that you can get json as a string

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Its not work for me. Because Im doing bulkInsert. So I need to create a database which can store System.string[] type data ?

Comment: That will be complicated. JSON could be stored as `varchar(max)` but SQL doesn't have arrays, so you will probably need to normalize the value with a one-to-many relationship

Comment: @GayanJ what I meant is you don't have to do anything - just use varchar... give me a minute - I'll answer the example

Answer (score 0):

Look - I create a table with json column and just dump it for bulk insert - notice it is saved as a string, so you can use varchar in SQL server

```
c143=# create table j(j json);
CREATE TABLE
c143=# insert into j select '{"p":{"n":3}}'::json;
INSERT 0 1
c143=# select * from j;
       j
---------------
 {"p":{"n":3}}
(1 row)
c143=# select j->>'p' from j;
 ?column?
----------
 {"n":3}
(1 row)
c143=# \q
Vladimirs-MacBook-Air:~ surname$ pg_dump
pg_dump        pg_dump_9.1.9  pg_dumpall
Vladimirs-MacBook-Air:~ surname$ pg_dump --inserts c143 -t j
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: j; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: vao; Tablespace:
--

CREATE TABLE j (
    j json
);


ALTER TABLE public.j OWNER TO vao;

--
-- Data for Name: j; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: vao
--

INSERT INTO j VALUES ('{"p":{"n":3}}');


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```